# DataTable plugin not working with dynamically generated php data?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

DataTable plugin not working with dynamically generated php data ?

I am using data table in to display a dynamic table. But its not working.
I tried to use static table its working I don't understand the problem
Here is my HTML Table and js script.
Can anyone solve the issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
  $('#myTable').dataTable(); 
 });
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="myTable">

<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Client Name</th>
<th width="100" height="30"align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">EPIC ID</th>
<th width="100" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Project Name</th>
<th width="100" height="30"align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Category</th>
<th width="100" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Epic Status</th>
<th width="150" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Total Estimated Hours</th>
<th width="150" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Total Time Spent</th>
<th width="150" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#999999" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" >% Hours Burned</th>
<th width="150" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">% Project Complete</th>
<th width="150" height="30" align="left" bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#d3d3d3">Action Status</th>
</tr> 
</thead>

<tbody> 
<tr <?php if($cnt%2==0){echo "bordercolor='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";}else{echo "bordercolor='#999999' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";}?>>
<td align="left" width="100" height="30"><?php echo "$ClientName";?></td>
<td align="left" width="100" height="30">
<?php 
    echo form_open('Riskreport',array('name'=>'s2frm'.$cnt,'target'=>'_blank'));?>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms.s2frm<?php echo $cnt;?>.submit()"><?php echo "$EPICID";?></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="epickeyid" value="<?php echo "$EPICID";?>" />
    <?php echo $formbuild;?>
    </form>       
    
   </td>
     <td align="left" width="100" height="30"><?php echo "$ProjectName";?></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" height="30"><?php echo "$Category";?></td>
     <td align="left" width="100" height="30"><?php echo "$epic_status";?></td>
     <td align="left" width="150" height="30"><?php echo "$TotalEstimatedHours";?></td>
     <td align="left" width="150" height="30"><?php echo "$TotalTimeSpentinHours";?></td>                
     <td align="left" width="150" height="30" <?php if(($variance2>0)&&($variance2<=100)){echo "bgcolor='#92d050'";}else if(($variance2>100)&&($variance2<=120)){echo "bgcolor='#FFC200'";}else if($variance2>120){echo "bgcolor='#ff0000'";}else{echo "bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";}?>><?php echo $variance2prcnt;?></td>
     <td align="left" width="150" height="30">
      <?php      
             $PrjtCompleteprcnt=$ops1->getprjctdone($EPICID);   
    echo $PrjtCompleteprcnt;
     ?> 
     </td>
     <td align="CENTER" width="150" height="30"><?php echo "$ActionStatus";?></td>   
       </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of [tag:CSS]? Styling a page should not take part in [tag:HTML] unless its for an email. I highly doubt that last part because of the [tag:Javascript]. And also, because PHP is executed, generates the page and then javascript loads up, the validity of your question comes into play.

Comment: Have you looked at the raw HTML to see what you are producing?   Whey are you even bothering with DataTables wiwith all of that inline css?

Comment: Actually this is PHP page for particular purpose I am using Inline CSS in php code.

Comment: Somewhat difficult to debug without seeing the output, check this JSFiddle and see if this is what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tynm20zu/